# JS form wont validate phone number

Tags: javascript, html

So i was making a simple web page to order a pizza as an assignment.
I am supposed to take in data and also supposed to validate the form as well.
so i wrote just a plain html and a simple JS code.
The name and the email validates, but when it comes to validating phone number, it doesn't validate. I wrote a simple(but wrong on extreme cases) RegEx for the phone number validation,
but it doesnt validate, i can write anything in the phone number textfield and the form accepts it when i click on submit.
Thanks for your help.

```js
function validateForm(){
    
    
    //validate name
    var name = document.getElementById("name").value;
    if(name=="" || !(/^[a-zA-Z ]+$/.test(name))){
        document.getElementById("name_error").innerHTML = "   Invalid Username";
        return false
    }


    //validate email
    var email = document.getElementById("em").value;
    var atposition=email.indexOf("@");  
    var dotposition=email.lastIndexOf(".");  
    if (email=="" || atposition<1 || dotposition<atposition+2 || dotposition+2>=x.length){  
        document.getElementById("email_error").innerHTML = "   Invalid Email"; 
        return false;   
    }  


    //validate phone Number
    var phno = document.getElementById("pno").value;
    if(phno == "" || !(/^[0-9]{10}$/.test(phno))){
        document.getElementById("phone_error").innerHTML = "   Invalid phone number";
        return false;
    }

    
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form name="form1" onsubmit = "return validateForm()">
        <fieldset>
            <legend>personal details</legend>
            <label for="name">Name:</label><br>
            <input type="text" name="Name" id="name"><span id="name_error"></span><br>
            <label for="em">Email:</label><br>
            <input type="text" name="e-mail" id="em" ><span id="email_error"></span><br>
            <label for="pno">Phone No.:</label><br>
            +91<input name="Phone Number" id="pno" maxlength="10"><span id="phone_error"></span><br>
        </fieldset>

        <fieldset>
            <legend>select pizza</legend>
            <input type="radio" id="simply_veg" name="select_pizza" value="Simpy Veg"><label for="simply_veg">Simply Veg</label><br>
            <input type="radio" id="veg_sup" name="select_pizza" value="Veg Supreme"><label for="veg_sup">Veg Supreme</label><br>
            <input type="radio" id="veg_del" name="select_pizza" value="Veg Delight"><label for="veg_del">Veg Delight</label><br>
            <div name="piz_not_sel"></div>
        </fieldset>

        <fieldset>
            <legend>select pizza size</legend>
            <input type="radio" id="pers_pan" name="select pizza size"><label for="pers_pan">Personal Pan</label><br>
            <input type="radio" id="med" name="select pizza size"><label for="med">Medium</label><br>
            <input type="radio" id="lar" name="select pizza size"><label for="lar">Large</label><br>
        </fieldset>

        <fieldset>
            <legend>select crust</legend>
            <input type="radio" id="thin" name="select crust"><label for="thin">Thin</label><br>
            <input type="radio" id="norm" name="select crust"><label for="norm">Normal</label><br>
            <input type="radio" id="spec" name="select crust"><label for="spec">Special</label><br>
        </fieldset>
            
        <fieldset>
            <legend>select payment option</legend>
            <label for="pay_opn">Choose a car:</label>
            <select id="pay_opn" name="pay_opn" required>
                <option value="COD">COD</option>
                <option value="Debit Card">Debit Card</option>
                <option value="Credit Card">Credit Card</option>
                <option value="UPI">UPI</option>
            </select><br>
        </fieldset>

        <fieldset>
            <legend>promo code</legend>
            <label for="code">Please enter code if any   </label><textarea id="code" name="code" rows="1" cols="9" maxlength="9" placeholder="PIZDIS090"></textarea><br>
        </fieldset>

        <fieldset>
            <legend>Terms and Conditions</legend>
            <input type="checkbox" id="tnc" name="termncond"><label for="tnc">I agree to the Terms and Conditions</label> 
        </fieldset>     
        
        <input type="submit" value="submit"><input type="reset">
        <div id="otpt"></div>
        
    </form>
    <script src="pizza_validate.js">
        
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

PS:There is something wierd i noticed that when I move the PhoneNumber validation block above that of Name block, it works perfectly from there on.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/pattern

Comment: thanks but i am required to do this in JS

Comment: I mean, you do what you gotta do to get the grade but understand that you are (hopefully) being prepared to build stuff in the real world and in the real world for this you'd use the pattern attribute on the input tag.

Answer (score 0):

Your return false statement will cause the reported behavior. Update the script as below. However this will show the validation messages, but not remove the validation messages, for that either add else condition and remove validation message for valid data or add `onblur/keyUp` events to handle this.

```
    function validateForm(){
    var isValid = true;
    //validate name
    var name = document.getElementById("name").value;
    if(name=="" || !(/^[a-zA-Z ]+$/.test(name))){
        document.getElementById("name_error").innerHTML = "   Invalid Username";
        isValid = false;
    }

    //validate email
    var email = document.getElementById("em").value;
    var atposition=email.indexOf("@");  
    var dotposition=email.lastIndexOf(".");  
    if (email=="" || atposition<1 || dotposition<atposition+2 || dotposition+2>=email.length){  
        document.getElementById("email_error").innerHTML = "   Invalid Email"; 
        isValid = false;
    }  


    //validate phone Number
    var phno = document.getElementById("pno").value;
    if(phno == "" || !(/^[0-9]{10}$/.test(phno))){
        document.getElementById("phone_error").innerHTML = "   Invalid phone number";
        isValid = false;
    }

    return isValid;
}
```

Comment: hi thanks for your suggestion, ig uess it did work cuz the invalid message now shows up near the phone number, but the form still submits even if two forms have correct data. for example, i kept correct data for name and email but wrong for ph.no, and pressed submit and the form cleared itself, i.e submit successful. please help, thank you

Comment: You have dotposition+2>=x.length condition for email check and x isn't defined anywhere. Correct it

Comment: thanks for letting me know, I have changed that and also added an else block to remove the error message as you suggested, although i am still not using isValid because i dont really need to mention all the errors at once, it can be done one after another. But the problem persists, the phone number doesnt get validated

Comment: With the above code i am able to see it is getting validated . May i know the scenario, which is not getting validated ?